# Passing values from the controller to view in Grails

Tags: grails

This is my controller code

```
def retrive(){
        println "Retrive Details"
        def stmt1 = PreparedStatementService.getValues()
        //render stmt1
        render view: 'test.gsp', model:[Sample:stmt1]
    }
```

where the `PreparedStatementService.getValues()` returns a list of values from the database. I am trying to print those values in the test.gsp but getting the output is `rs698: null`

Comment: <!DOCTYPE html>
<%@ page import="com.ws.Sample" %>
<html>
 <head>
 </head>
  <title>Grails Test</title>
  <body>
   <g:each var="testing" in="${Sample}">
    <g:if test="${testing == null }">
     Null values
    </g:if>
    <g:else>
     ${testing.value}<br/>
    </g:else>  
   </g:each>
    
   Testing of grails
  </body>
</html>

Comment: This is my gsp page

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to specify the .gsp suffix in your render statement.

I think lowercase would be better for the key in your model map i.e. samples

Is 'value' the name of a field in your list of samples?

Also you don't need to do ${testing == null} just ${!testing} will do although I'm not sure you'll have any nulls in your collection.